# Declaring a Double in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Calculator
{


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner mortgage = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(mortgage.nextLine());
        double iRate;
        double lAmount;
        double answer;
        System.out.println("Enter interest rate");
        iRate = mortgage.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter loan amount");
        lAmount = mortgage.nextDouble();
        answer = iRate + lAmount;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

}
```

My question is I don't think I am declaring the double correctly and am getting an error. How do I declare the double correctly so the program runs without error

Comment: When you ask about an error, it's helpful to include the details of the error.

Comment: If you get an error, it would be wise to show us the error here in your question, right?

Comment: No compile-time or run-time error for me.

Answer (score 5):

That code compiles fine although:

```
System.out.println(mortgage.nextLine());
```

seems a bit strange since you wait for a line then print it out. Not sure *why* you would want to do that.

The following code with that line removed and some cosmetic changes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner mortgage = new Scanner (System.in);
        double iRate, lAmount, answer;

        System.out.println ("Enter interest rate");
        iRate = mortgage.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Enter loan amount");
        lAmount = mortgage.nextDouble();

        answer = iRate + lAmount;
        System.out.println ("Answer is " + answer);
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
Enter interest rate
10
Enter loan amount
50000
Answer is 50010.0
```

---

You may also want to rethink the way in which you do interest rate calculations. Anyone who's ever done work for a bank would get a giggle out of that.

The general way to calculate the interest due on some capital for a given percentage rate would be something like:

```
answer = iRate / 100.0 * lAmount;
```

although I realise you may have intended to clean that up once you get past your immediate problem, so apologies for that friendly jab :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having to guess since you didn't specify the error, but it's likely coming from your usage of `mortgage.nextDouble();`. `nextDouble();` will read JUST the next double from the line you type in, meaning there will be a trailing newline character at the end, which will result in it behaving in ways you don't expect.

There's a few alternative ways to go about it, so I'll just show one here:

```
double iRate;
iRate = Double.parseDouble(mortgage.nextLine());
```

Mind you, this does as much sanity checking as your code (as in, none!). What this does is read in a line of input, and then have the Double class convert the resulting `String` into a `Double`, which is stored in the `double` iRate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your "Enter interest rate" line to appear first, remove `System.out.println(mortgage.nextLine());`; it's not doing anything. Your program is waiting for an input before it can proceed, which I think was your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use double's (or float's) for money or any other calculations, have a look at this article "[don't use floats for money](http://www.java-tips.be/blog/don-t-use-floats-for-money)". basicly it IEEE 754 giving you all kind of rounding errors.